# Update in stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to receive `NIC` number of employee which is kinda ID number for them and change from one to another team based on time period.

So, I have 4 teams responsible of developing a software which each employee can participate in different teams in a different period of time. For instance, I have a employee `NIC` number 54323 and belongs to 3 different groups. But when I execute query says 1 row affected but when I do `select * from StuffTeams where  NIC = 54323`It didn't change anything.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE sp_TransferTeam
    @NIC int,
    @IDTeam1 int,
    @IDTeam2 int,
    @StartDate date,
    @EndDate date
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @NIC = NIC 
    FROM StuffTeams 
    WHERE IDTeam = @IDTeam1 

    UPDATE StuffTeams 
    SET IDTeam = @IDTeam2 
    WHERE NIC = @NIC 
      AND DateStart = @StartDate 
      AND DateFinish = @EndDate
END

EXEC sp_TransferTeam 54323, 4, 2, '2017-08-01', '2017-10-01'
```

StuffTeam table:

```
CREATE TABLE StuffTeams
(
    IDStuffTeam nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,
    IDTeam int NOT NULL,
    NIC int NOT NULL,
    DateStart date NOT NULL,
    DateFinish date NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Stuff PRIMARY KEY (IDStuffTeam),
    CONSTRAINT FK_sTeam FOREIGN KEY (IDTeam) REFERENCES Teams (IDTeam),
    CONSTRAINT FK_sNIC FOREIGN KEY (NIC) REFERENCES Employees (NIC),
)
```

In any case team table:

```
CREATE TABLE Teams 
(
    IDTeam int NOT NULL,
    IDProduct int NOT NULL,
    TeamName nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,
    DateStart date NOT NULL,
    DateFinish date NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Team PRIMARY KEY (IDTeam),
    CONSTRAINT FK_IDProduct FOREIGN KEY (IDProduct) REFERENCES Products (IDProduct)
)
```

Many thanks

Comment: You're passing in @NIC as a parameter into the proc but then it's immediately getting reset by the first query in the proc.

Comment: But if I don't put @NIC as a parameter how can I execute without receiving NIC number of employee

Comment: If you're passing in the value for @NIC as a parameter, then you already know that value before you execute the proc.  But you're then potentially resetting that value in your first query since it's relying on other parameter values that you're passing.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Thank you so much for reminding! Someone already told me this before but my professor wants stored procedures as sp_ and triggers as tr_ . That's why I'm using like that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your sp as below

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE sp_TransferTeam
    @NIC int,
    @IDTeam1 int,
    @IDTeam2 int,
    @StartDate date,
    @EndDate date
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE StuffTeams 
    SET IDTeam = @IDTeam2 
    WHERE NIC = @NIC 
      AND DateStart = @StartDate 
      AND DateFinish = @EndDate
END

EXEC sp_TransferTeam 54323, 4, 2, '2017-08-01', '2017-10-01'
```

then select from outside to see results

Comment: Thank you so much! It solves my problem but can you briefly explain why I shouldn't use select in sp

Comment: The problem was that your select Statement was changing @nic . If you remove that, you vould use select statement inside sp as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare @NIC as a variable not a parameter and then set it with your first query. A good way to debug would be select the records using that where clause outside your SP and then see if all the records you are targeting are being selected or not.

```
SELECT * FROM StuffTeams
    WHERE NIC = 54323 
      AND DateStart = '2017-08-01' 
      AND DateFinish = '2017-10-01'
```

Try running this and see if it returns records you want to update. Your where clause might be filtering them out. If not that try changing your date format of the passed dates to MM-DD-YYYY.

Comment: But if I use like that I can't execute for other employees also. I have to alter sp everytime I want to search a query

Comment: I tried to do this as a query but no results.. and when I declare @NIC there is an error says; Procedure or function sp_TransferTeam has too many arguments specified. Because I'cant put NIC number in exec query

Comment: Could you please post the records you are trying to update? If the query didn't return anything then your where clause might be wrong and its filtering out the records you want to update. The query should have returned the records to be updated. And sorry for the confusion I didn't mean you add that to your final SP I meant run it as a query just for testing purposes.